# Wordpress Custom Sidebar

Tags: html, css, wordpress, sidebar

I am updating my portfolio website and require a different sidebar for different ties of pages, i.e. one for work page and one for the blog page, apparently this can be done using Custom Fields in the page or post.

So, I opened up single.php and found the following code

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

And replaced it with the code below

```
<?php $sidebar = get_post_meta($post->ID, "sidebar", true);
get_sidebar($sidebar);
?>
```

To add a custom sidebar, all I need to do now is apparently add the custom field “Sidebar” and include the name of the sidebar file. For example if I insert “page-01”, it will display sidebar-page-01.php as your sidebar.

After multiple times of trying however this 'isn't' the case, can't see anything wrong with what I am doing, any one have any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this the way you are doing it by doing your own php function and target the page you need with

```
<?php
    if ( is_home() ) :
        get_sidebar( 'home' );
    elseif ( is_portfolio page1() ) :
       get_sidebar( 'portfolio page sidebar' );
    else :
       get_sidebar();
    endif;
?>
```

add more elseif statements for as many page & sidebar combination you will have

or you can download [this](http://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/) plugin and use the code above the same way

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @LOTUSMS ideally, I want my website plugin free, but if worst comes to worst and I need to use this then so be it :)

Comment: Kudos on that. Like I said, use the code you wrote and identify the pages with the is_page.

Comment: you've lost me there, I have replaced the original sidebar code in my single.php, however I can't find where I would identify the post with is_page ?? Any tips ? Thanks again

Comment: Hi @LOTUSMS thanks for your reply and all your help, I can see how this works however, how exactly would I go about getting each post to recognise each sidebar ??

Comment: @user3380148 Each wordpress page has a template. Have a look at which template you're using on your pages

Comment: If you want each post to have a different sidebar assigned to it, add the post permalink identifier where is_home and is_portfolio page is. Posts have their own page in wordpress. Use that. i.e. if ( is_post1()); get_sidebar('sidebar for post1' );..etc

Comment: You got it! Thanks @LOTUSMS (y)

Comment: No problem! Giving me credit for my answer wouldn't hurt tho lol